# How to compare field values across instances in a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to construct a queryset in Django where the values of one field are not contained within any instance of the same table. As an example, take this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I can get a non-duplicate queryset using the following loop:

```
from django.db.models import Q
not_contained = MyModel.objects.all()
for instance in MyModel.objects.all():
    not_contained=not_contained.exclude(Q(text__contains=instance.text) & ~Q(id=instance.id))
```

My question if if there a way of doing this more directly and avoid the explicit loop here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can some use extra() here.

For example:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
[<MyModel: unique>, <MyModel: onemore>, <MyModel: foo>, <MyModel: bar>, <MyModel: bar123>]
>>> MyModel.objects.extra(select={'cnt': 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM myapp_mymodel B WHERE B.text LIKE "%%" || myapp_mymodel.text || "%%"'}, where=['cnt = 1'])
[<MyModel: unique>, <MyModel: onemore>, <MyModel: foo>, <MyModel: bar123>]
```

As you see, second queryset doesn't contain 'bar'. Disadvantage with extra is it's DBMS-specific. Example is for sqlite (for mysql you probably need to replace || with CONCAT, etc).

If you have troubles understanding code, sql query can help:

```
>>> print MyModel.objects.extra(select={'cnt': 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM myapp_mymodel B WHERE B.text LIKE "%%" || myapp_mymodel.text || "%%"'}, where=['cnt = 1']).query
SELECT (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM myapp_mymodel B WHERE B.text LIKE "%" || myapp_mymodel.text || "%") AS "cnt", "myapp_mymodel"."id", "myapp_mymodel"."text" FROM "myapp_mymodel" WHERE (cnt = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up using a raw sql command using a cursor, as I was not aware of the `.extra()` option. Will try to use this, its nice as it returns a queryset like any other filtering.